# Which files have names from result dir(scrapy) command?

Tags: python, scrapy

With the follow commands I see names inside `scrapy` module:

```
>>>import scrapy
>>>dir(scrapy)
['Field', 'FormRequest', 'Item', 'Request', 'Selector', 'Spider', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__version__', '_txv', 'exceptions', 'http', 'item', 'link', 'selector', 'signals', 'spiders', 'twisted_version', 'utils', 'version_info']
```

In the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html) is said:

> A module is a file containing Python definitions and statements.

So I try find `scrapy` file to see definitions names inside:

```
$find / -name "scrapy*" -print
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/templates/project/scrapy.cfg
/usr/local/bin/scrapy
/root/tutorial/scrapy.cfg
```

But inside that files no have any names like dir(scrapy) results.

I'm complete new in python and OO, an try understand more about flush in `Scrapy Framework`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After importing a module, just type the module name again to see the actual file corresponding to that module

```
>>> import scrapy
>>> scrapy
<module 'scrapy' from 'venv/scrapy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/__init__.pyc'>
```

From the above output, we can see that it is from the file `'venv/scrapy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/__init__.pyc'` and the corresponding python source file would be `'venv/scrapy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/__init__.py'`

If you openthe file `'venv/scrapy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/__init__.py'` in your favourite editor, you see that it imports a lot from sub-modules

```
# Declare top-level shortcuts
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy.http import Request, FormRequest
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
```

So if you want to see the definition for  `'Item'`, you chave to check the file `item.py` under `venv/scrapy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/`

Comment: if module are a file, why `__init__` have no module named?